# What's the JPA persistence-unit lifecycle in an OSGI container?

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, openjpa, fuseesb

**Scenario**

- OSGI bundle running in JBoss Fuse ESB
- JPA persistence-unit with OpenJPA as implementation
- H2 database for the datasource referenced by JNDI
- OpenJPA instructed to create schema via `SynchonriseMappings`

**Question**

When does the persistence-unit start and load the tables and is there a way to influence this behavior?

The reason I ask this is that I had a bit of custom SQL to run on the created database on init which I tried invoking using blueprint `init-method` and OSGI bundle activators but each time the tables weren't there yet.

I also tried making the bean which ran the script depend on `EntityManager` but again no joy. I even tried lazy loading using the first message as a trigger to ensure that the bundle was fully started before attempting it and again the tables don't exist yet.

The only way I could make it work was to make a dummy call to the entity, e.g., `entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, -1);`, before my SQL, I did this through an `init-method` but it would also work in an activator I'm sure.

This was behavior I hadn't ever noticed before in many years of using JPA and would like to understand it for my own sanity.

This is just for a mock implementation of a 3rd party service, hence the weird requirements to have JPA create the schema and run a SQL file on start.